# If condition fails in Razor view throwing error "Sequence contains no matching elements"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project I have an action method and the part of view where I am having problem are attached below.

The problem is with IF condition in View Model.Transaction.count() >0 ,If the condition is true there is no problem , but if that Condition fails(Transaction count is 0) it is throwing Exception saying "Sequence contains no matching elements"

Please someone help me..!!

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
    { 
        Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
        try
        {

            order.OrderItems = db.OrderItems.Where(e => e.OrderID == id).ToList();

            int EventID = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VirtualEventID"]);

            order.Ticketservices = db_Tradevent.Ticketservices.Where(t => t.TEEventID == EventID)
                                                                .Where(t => t.EntityID == order.OrderID)
                                                                .ToList();

            order.Transactions = db_Tradevent.TrackerTransactions.Where(t => t.TEEventID == EventID)
                                                                .Where(t => t.OrderID == order.OrderID)
                                                                .Where(t => t.TransactionStatusID == 2).ToList();


            bool HasERT = false;

            foreach (var orderitem in order.OrderItems)
            {
                orderitem.Trackers = db.Trackers.Where(e => e.OrderItemID == orderitem.OrderItemID).ToList();

                foreach (var tracker in orderitem.Trackers)
                {
                    tracker.Qualifiers = db.Qualifiers.Where(e => e.TrackerID == tracker.TrackerID).OrderBy(s => s.QualifierID).ToList();
                }

                if (orderitem.EventProduct.Product.Type == "ERT")
                {
                    HasERT = true;
                }
            }

            @ViewBag.HasERT = HasERT;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }

        return View(order);
    }enter code here
```

**The part of view where I am having problem is given below**

```
@if (Model.OrderStatusID == 3 && Model.Transactions.Count() > 0)
    {
        if (Model.Transactions.SingleOrDefault(t => t.OrderID == Model.OrderID).TransactionMethodID == 2)
        {
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Surcharge
                </td>
                <td colspan="@(ViewBag.HasERT ? 3 : 2)" style="color: Green; text-align: right">
                    @(Model.Transactions.Single(t => t.OrderID == Model.OrderID).TransactionAmount - (decTotal / 10 + decTotal))
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is after the if condition ? Are you having accessing a collection after that ?

Comment: After if I have table row in which I wanted to display as per  IF condition..(the view code is attached for reference)

Comment: First of all, Do not do all complex where clauses and logics in views.Do that in your controllers/services and send a flat-lean-clean view model to the view.

Comment: I agree with you, but as per my requirement have to dynamically render this <tr>. when I have transactions in the model then only I have to render this <tr> if not I should not, How can I do that any thoughts please??

Comment: Check if `order.Transactions` is not null. If it is null then just initialize it with empty list `order.Transactions = new List<Transactions>();`

Comment: Thanks akshay..!!  I am trying to retrieve something from null in this line of code in the view  @(Model.Transactions.Single(t => t.OrderID == Model.OrderID).TransactionAmount - (decTotal / 10 + decTotal))    so it's throwing error. Hope it helps someone..!!